# What can I do to make my program (save as pdf File like Microsoft Excel)

Tags: java

Please, is it possible to make a (call) or a program that does the same thing when I save an xls file as pdf format.
in a java program is using JAVA API Jxl or something else

I find an example

```
import officetools.OfficeFile; // from officetools.jar

FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File("test.doc")); 
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File("test.pdf"));

OfficeFile f = new OfficeFile(fis,"localhost","8100", false);

f.convert(fos,"pdf");
```

But it required the openOffice is there something else like PDF crator on Excel changing  extension automaticly on my program

Comment: I don't know if there's a solution for this out of the box. AFAIK you can use iText to generate PDF files using Java.

Comment: yes thank you .. I used this API but unfortunately I am forced to go through all the xls file for cells .. I see that the use of a program like pdf creator at the option of Excel with save as pdf option is very great. can we use this service to Microsoft Excel

Comment: Did you read this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7735697/how-to-convert-ms-excel-file-to-pdf-in-java

Comment: @MoritzPetersen that's covered in OP's last comment. And yes, looks like there's no other way to solve it.

Comment: Yes ,think you @MoritzPetersen yes I saw it thank you.but I as say I wont Io do like OfficeFile ..3 simple ligne code ...

Comment: Because when I try It with org.apache.poi.hssf .Ihave many problem ..there is cells not exist and some image ect......

Comment: @salvador But [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7737037/1277252) does exactly what you want: 1 line of code, not Office installation required.

Comment: @MoritzPetersen I want something like this  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16457411/sava-as-pdf-a-file-xls-with-java-program-automaticly-like-microsoft-excel

Answer (score 1):

Check this example here [Covert doc, excel, text and images to PDF](http://dulawisdom.blogspot.com/2010/11/covert-doc-excel-text-and-images-to-pdf.html) which uses iText and apache poi

downlaod iText from http://itextpdf.com/

downlaod apache poi from http://poi.apache.org/download.html

you can also use this example below to convert Microsoft Office Word File to PDF

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import com.lowagie.text.Document;
import com.lowagie.text.DocumentException;
import com.lowagie.text.Paragraph;
import com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfWriter;


import org.apache.poi.hwpf.HWPFDocument;
import org.apache.poi.hwpf.extractor.WordExtractor;

import org.apache.poi.hwpf.usermodel.Range;
import org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.POIFSFileSystem;


public class DocToPDF{

public static void main(String[] args) {

    POIFSFileSystem fs = null;  
    Document document = new Document();

     try {  

         fs = new POIFSFileSystem(new FileInputStream("D:/test.doc"));  

         HWPFDocument doc = new HWPFDocument(fs);  
         WordExtractor we = new WordExtractor(doc);  

         OutputStream file = new FileOutputStream(new File("D:/test.pdf")); 

         PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, file);  

         Range range = doc.getRange();
         document.open();  
         writer.setPageEmpty(true);  
         document.newPage();  
         writer.setPageEmpty(true);  

         String[] paragraphs = we.getParagraphText();  
         for (int i = 0; i < paragraphs.length; i++) {  

             org.apache.poi.hwpf.usermodel.Paragraph pr = range.getParagraph(i);

             paragraphs[i] = paragraphs[i].replaceAll("\\cM?\r?\n", "");  
         System.out.println("Length:" + paragraphs[i].length());  
         System.out.println("Paragraph" + i + ": " + paragraphs[i].toString());  

         // add the paragraph to the document  
         document.add(new Paragraph(paragraphs[i]));  
         }  

         System.out.println("Finished");  
     } catch (Exception e) {  
         e.printStackTrace();  
     } finally {  
                     // close the document  
        document.close();  
                 }  
     }  
}
```

Comment: Thx @Mohamed Alaghbari ..this is works fine But it is not like the format when I do save as pdf file withe Microsoft Excel :( think you very much

Comment: welcome my frined ,,,I will try to get you a better solution to get a better vote... you may vote the answer may others get benefited from it